# turn off javascript using css?

Tags: javascript, mobile, css, media-queries

I have used a media query to direct mobile visitors to a separate, mobile specific stylesheet. The problem is that there are elements on the index page which use JS and I need to have this switched off for the mobile version - how do I do this?

Added note: I am unfamiliar with JS - I can work with html and css and used other folks js :-/

Regarding some of the comments below, I am concerned about load times in mobile due to loading unnecessary code. Could someone be kind enough to tell me what to add to my  element to tell the doc to only load js if NOT mobile? Is that the right question to ask?

Comment: There are so many question regarding detect mobile users.

Comment: I don't think it can be done using CSS... Have you tried doing it with JS?

Comment: Why don't you use the same logic you used to redirect to the mobile stylesheet to set a flag you can check in your JS code to determine if it should run?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to ONLY load scripts NEEDED for the mobile version. As many device have a data-cap, you don't want the user to be loading scripts that they don't need. So, you would detect their browser via PHP, or JavaScript, and then load the required files for their platform.

Comment: thanks, yes my concern too as mentioned in new edit to my original question. I do not have the mastery of js to add code at will (am working on it). I am concerned about causing unnecessary slow load times on mobile by loading unneeded script. How could I prevent a mobile device from loading script? By using a different stylesheet for mobile I was hoping there would be something I could add to it to say "do not load any js"

Comment: CSS is not a scripting language. There is no way for it to say whether or not to load a script. The only way you could do this, would be to detect if they are using an iOS device (and whatever else is a smart phone), or if they are using a computer. This can only be done using languages like JavaScript or PHP.

Comment: Here is the code I use in javascript to detect the browser/device. I'm not sure what terms you would need to add to detect android or windows phone though. http://jsfiddle.net/udHVN/

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a script that also detects the same specs your media queries does? that way you can selectively activate scripts.

One such script exists in the [1140 CSS Grid](http://cssgrid.net/) framework to support media queries on older browsers. You can check it out and see how you can tap into it.

[Here's an article](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/) that explains how to check the screen width and height to emulate media query screen detection.

By the way. CSS is for styling, nothing more.

Comment: your right I have forgoten my css ABCs - it's for styling only

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean that there are elements on the page with scripts embedded within them.  The first thing you need to do is get rid of embedded scripts such as onclick attributes on elements.  These scripts need to be moved into their own external JS files.  Once this is done, you can only include the JS files for the mobile version of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

You can have a script that loads all the other scripts when in desktop, this is a good option if you're using only non-intrusive Javascript (e.g jquery).

Another option is not to generate those scripts in the first place in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are probably the best solution for providing alternative styles for mobile users. Unfortunately there is no `media` attribute for the `<script>` element to proceed similarly in the case of page logic.

You can, however, provide a script loader which will load desired `.js` file depending on the style sheet selected by the browser on the basis of your media query. I don't know how to do this in a direct, elegant way but there is a nice hack for that. You have to "mark" each `.css` with a unique declaration (dummy, unimportant or different by design) and check it from within JS after the page has loaded to determine which style sheet has been applied by the browser.

The CSS could look like this:

```
@media handheld, screen and (max-width:1023px) {
    body {margin-top: 1px}
}
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    body {margin-top: 0px}
}
/* These would be separate .css files in a real example */
```

And the accompanying JS as follows:

```
window.setTimeout('wait()', 10);
function wait() {
    if (!document.body)
        window.setTimeout('wait()', 100)
    else
       onLoad();
}

function onLoad() {
    var load = document.createElement('script');
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var mark = window.getComputedStyle(body).getPropertyValue('margin-top');
    switch (mark) {
        case '0px':
            load.setAttribute('src', 'handheld.js');
            break;
        case '1px':
            load.setAttribute('src', 'screen.js');
            break;
        default:
            load.setAttribute('src', 'somethingelse.js');
    }
    head.appendChild(load);
}
```